# Dowloading all Urls accessible under a given domain with wget without saving the actual pages?

Tags: linux, bash, python, wget

Hi trying to determine all the valid urls under a given domain without having the mirror the site locally.

People generally want to download all the pages but I just want to get a list of the direct urls under a given domain (e.g. www.example.com), which would be something like www.example.com/page1, www.example.com/page2, etc.

Is there a way to use wget to do this? or is there a better tool for this?

Comment: In order to determine the links on each page, you will need to see the page (I.e. Download it)

Comment: @BrianAdkins: I am Ok with downloading but I woant to keep only the urls not the pages' contents

Comment: There's a `--spider` option that downloads the page, but doesn't save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a crude script:

```
curl -s whaturl |
  grep -o "<a href=[^>]*>" |
  sed -r 's/<a href="([^"]*)".*>/\1/' |
  sort -u
```

The `grep` picks all the `href`s. The `sed` picks out the url part from the `href`. The `sort` filters out duplicate links.

It will also work with `wget -O -` in place of `curl -s`.

Example output:

```
$ curl -s http://stackexchange.com/users/148837/lesmana?tab=accounts | grep -o "<a href=[^>]*>" | sed -r 's/<a href="([^"]*)".*>/\1/' | sort -u
/
/about
/about/contact
/blogs
/leagues
/legal
/legal/privacy-policy
/newsletters
/questions
/sites
/users/148837/lesmana
/users/148837/lesmana?tab=activity
/users/148837/lesmana?tab=favorites
/users/148837/lesmana?tab=reputation
/users/148837/lesmana?tab=subscriptions
/users/148837/lesmana?tab=top
/users/login?returnurl=%2fusers%2f148837%2flesmana%3ftab%3daccounts
http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/16563/lesmana
http://askubuntu.com/users/1366/
http://blog.stackexchange.com
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/
http://chat.stackexchange.com/
http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/2790/
http://meta.stackoverflow.com
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147747/
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/116/
http://serverfault.com/users/45166/
http://stackoverflow.com/users/360899/
http://superuser.com/users/39401/
http://twitter.com/stackexchange
http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1170/
http://www.facebook.com/stackexchange
https://plus.google.com/+StackExchange
```

Comment: Very nice! I had ignored CURL because it can't recurse. I found that **httrack** solves this problem adequately.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I had to find my own answer:

the tool I use was **httrack**.

```
httrack -p0 -r2 -d www.example.com
```

- the *-p0* option tells it to just scan (not save pages);
- the *-rx* option tells it the depth of the search
- the *-d* options tells it to stay on the same principal domain

there is even a -%L  to add the scanned URL to the specified file but it doesn't seem to work. But that's not a problem, because under the hts-cache directory you can find a **TSV** file named *new.txt* containing all the urls visited  and some additional information about it. I could extract the URLs from it with the following python code:

```
with open("hts-cache/new.txt") as f:
    t = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for l in t:
        print l['URL']
```